# TVML background not updating when image updates

Tags: tvos, tvml

When a "product image" (a.k.a. the `heroImg`) is first displayed in my `ProductTemplate` TVML layout, the background is automatically set to a blurred copy of the image.

The image itself is updating when I ask it to:

```
function changeHeroImage(incomingString) {
    if (incomingString) {
        var theHero = myDoc.getElementsByTagName("heroImg").item(0);
        theHero.setAttribute('src', incomingString);
    }
}
```

.. but not the background; the layout retains the background from the original image. Any idea on how to force the background to update, to reflect the current image?

Comment: Apple wrote they have "..confirmed that we don’t support swapping of images in the templates..", which I interpret to say: one cannot refresh the background purely by changing the image. Of course, one can refresh the background by reloading the entire document, but that causes a slight flash to white in between. Feature request!

Comment: Did you ever find a way to change the background image? I don't except that it isn't possible because the Apple's own website shows the HBO app with a contextual background based on the focused item https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/user-interaction/

Comment: @chris, though I haven't checked on this limitation for a year now, I would suspect the HBO app is not relying solely on the preset templates.